# WLAN weak network issue on Qualcomm Atheros AR9285

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, atheros

I have HP Notebook 630 and running 16.04. It is an old laptop and is using driver **ath9k**. On running command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` I got this as output-

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
DeviceName: Atheros AR3011 Bluetooth 2.1+EDR  Adapter 
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [103c:1461]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: ath9k
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5209] (rev 01)
```

I searched for solutions but nothing worked for me now (some I do not understand).

**Please comment the correct link before marking it duplicate. Let me try that solution and I will comment back if solution worked.**

Comment: What is "weak network issue"?

Comment: I am having problem in connecting to wifi networks. I need to take my laptop closer to let the connection happen, while all other laptops establish connection even at more distance. It is not the laptop problem as I am able to connect in Windows.

Comment: it looks like a hardware problem, like a bad antenna contact.

Comment: Its not a hardware problem sir, I run dual boot and everything is fine on Windows.